# How can I make my "two legged" modular robot to move in Gazebo (it seems "pinned" by a fixed joint and unmovable)?

Tags: ros2, moveit, ros2-control, ros2-controllers, gazebo-ros2-control

I am currently working on a "two legs" modular robot (cuboctaedric units with some revolute joints) and I have to make it move in Gazebo.
Here is what it looks like :
[image]

[image]

I built this model starting with the cylindrical link at the top (the one between the two "legs"), and there is a fixed joint between this link and a virtual link named world. Here is the URDF file I created for this robot :

```
<link name="world"/>


<!-- virtual joint -->
<joint name="virtual_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="link1"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.99"/>
</joint>


<link name="link1">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="${pi/2.0} 0 ${pi/2.0}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.04" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>
    
    <collision>
        <origin rpy="${pi/2.0} 0 ${pi/2.0}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.04" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="0.5" r="0.1" h="0.04" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2.0} 0 ${pi/2.0}" />
</link>


<!-- left arm -->
<joint name="top_left" type="revolute">
    <parent link="link1" />
    <child link="link2" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.02 0 0" />
    <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit effort="411" lower="-${2*pi}" upper="${2*pi}" velocity="${pi}"/>
    <dynamics damping="60.0" friction="4.0" />
</joint>


<link name="link2">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="-0.14 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="-0.14 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:box_inertia m="1.0" l="0.28" w="0.28" h="0.28" xyz="-0.14 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<!-- test représentation cuboctaèdre par cube pour inertia -->
<!-- <link name="link2">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.14 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.28 0.28 0.28" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>
</link> -->


<joint name="joint2_3" type="fixed">
    <parent link="link2" />
    <child link="link3" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.14 0 -0.28" />
</joint>


<link name="link3">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:box_inertia m="1.0" l="0.28" w="0.28" h="0.28" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<joint name="joint3_4" type="fixed">
    <parent link="link3" />
    <child link="link4" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.15"/>
</joint>


<link name="link4">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="-${pi} 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.01" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.02 0.02 0.02" filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/joint1_z.stl" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="-${pi} 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.01" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.02 0.02 0.02" filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/joint1_z.stl" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="1.0" r="0.1" h="0.18" xyz="0 0 -0.08" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<!-- test représentation joint1_z par cylindre pour inertia -->
<!-- <link name="link4">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.08" />
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.18" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>
</link> -->


<joint name="middle_left" type="revolute">
    <parent link="link4" />
    <child link="link5" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.13" />
    <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit effort="411" lower="-${2*pi}" upper="${2*pi}" velocity="${pi}"/>
    <dynamics damping="60.0" friction="4.0" />
</joint>


<link name="link5">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.065" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.065" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:sphere_inertia m="0.5" r="0.065" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<joint name="joint5_6" type="fixed">
    <parent link="link5" />
    <child link="link6" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.13"/>
</joint>


<link name="link6">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 -${pi/2}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.02 0.02 0.02" filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/joint1_z.stl" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 -${pi/2}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.02 0.02 0.02" filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/joint1_z.stl" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="1.0" r="0.1" h="0.18" xyz="0 0 0.07" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<!-- test représentation joint1_z par cylindre pour inertia -->
<!-- <link name="link6">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.07" />
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.18" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>
</link> -->


<joint name="bottom_left" type="revolute">
    <parent link="link6" />
    <child link="link7" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.15" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit effort="411" lower="-${2*pi}" upper="${2*pi}" velocity="${pi}"/>
    <dynamics damping="60.0" friction="4.0" />
</joint>


<link name="link7">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0 0 -0.01" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0 0 -0.01" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:box_inertia m="1.0" l="0.28" w="0.28" h="0.28" xyz="0 0 -0.01" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<!-- right arm -->
<joint name="top_right" type="revolute">
    <parent link="link1" />
    <child link="link8" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.02 0 0" />
    <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit effort="411" lower="-${2*pi}" upper="${2*pi}" velocity="${pi}"/>
    <dynamics damping="60.0" friction="4.0" />
</joint>


<link name="link8">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0.14 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0.14 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:box_inertia m="1.0" l="0.28" w="0.28" h="0.28" xyz="0.14 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<joint name="joint8_9" type="fixed">
    <parent link="link8" />
    <child link="link9" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.14 0 -0.28" />
</joint>


<link name="link9">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:box_inertia m="1.0" l="0.28" w="0.28" h="0.28" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<joint name="joint9_10" type="fixed">
    <parent link="link9" />
    <child link="link10" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.15"/>
</joint>


<link name="link10">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="-${pi} 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.01" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.02 0.02 0.02" filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/joint1_z.stl" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="-${pi} 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.01" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.02 0.02 0.02" filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/joint1_z.stl" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="1.0" r="0.1" h="0.18" xyz="0 0 -0.08" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<joint name="middle_right" type="revolute">
    <parent link="link10" />
    <child link="link11" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.13" />
    <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit effort="411" lower="-${2*pi}" upper="${2*pi}" velocity="${pi}"/>
    <dynamics damping="60.0" friction="4.0" />
</joint>


<link name="link11">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.065" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.065" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:sphere_inertia m="0.5" r="0.065" xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<joint name="joint11_12" type="fixed">
    <parent link="link11" />
    <child link="link12" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.13"/>
</joint>


<link name="link12">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 -${pi/2}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.02 0.02 0.02" filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/joint1_z.stl" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 -${pi/2}" xyz="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.02 0.02 0.02" filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/joint1_z.stl" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="1.0" r="0.1" h="0.18" xyz="0 0 0.07" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<joint name="bottom_right" type="revolute">
    <parent link="link12" />
    <child link="link13" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 -0.15" />
    <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit effort="411" lower="-${2*pi}" upper="${2*pi}" velocity="${pi}"/>
    <dynamics damping="60.0" friction="4.0" />
</joint>


<link name="link13">
    <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0 0 -0.01" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin rpy="0 0 ${pi/4.0}" xyz="0 0 -0.01" />
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://modrobot_description/meshes/cuboctahedron.stl" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" />
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <xacro:box_inertia m="1.0" l="0.28" w="0.28" h="0.28" xyz="0 0 -0.01" rpy="0 0 0" />
</link>


<!-- Transmissions-->
<xacro:default_transmission name="top_left"/>
<xacro:default_transmission name="middle_left"/>
<xacro:default_transmission name="bottom_left"/>
<xacro:default_transmission name="top_right"/>
<xacro:default_transmission name="middle_right"/>
<xacro:default_transmission name="bottom_right"/>
```

I also defined controllers for the joints with the JointTrajectoryController for Gazebo and MoveIt. Here is my controllers.yaml :

controller_manager:
ros__parameters:
update_rate: 10

```
left_arm_controller:
  type : joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

right_arm_controller:
  type : joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

joint_state_broadcaster:
  type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
```

left_arm_controller:
ros__parameters:
joints:
- top_left
- middle_left
- bottom_left

```
command_interfaces:
  - position

state_interfaces:
  - position

open_loop_control: true
allow_integration_in_goal_trajectories: true
```

right_arm_controller:
ros__parameters:
joints:
- top_right
- middle_right
- bottom_right

```
command_interfaces:
  - position

state_interfaces:
  - position

open_loop_control: true
allow_integration_in_goal_trajectories: true
```

And here is the moveit_controllers.yaml :

```
moveit_controller_manager: moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager

moveit_simple_controller_manager:  

controller_names:
- left_arm_controller
- right_arm_controller  

left_arm_controller:
action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
type: FollowJointTrajectory
default: true
joints:
  - top_left
  - middle_left
  - bottom_left  

right_arm_controller:
action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
type: FollowJointTrajectory
default: true
joints:
  - top_right
  - middle_right
  - bottom_right
```

Problem is, when I move the joints of my robot and it doesn't touch the ground anymore, it doesn't fall in Gazebo, the cylindrical link is pinned and so is the rest of the robot :
[image: The robot doesn't touch the ground but doesn't fall]

Ideally I would like to make the robot move like this :
[Automated movement](https://amiraa.pages.cba.mit.edu/self-replicating-hierarchical-modular-robotic-swarms/recursive_swarm/demos/indexRecursion.html)

[Manual movement](https://amiraa.pages.cba.mit.edu/self-replicating-hierarchical-modular-robotic-swarms/recursive_swarm/demos/indexIK_parts.html)

Is ther a way to achieve this in ROS2 ?